# Delete a printer with the REG ADD command. Minor syntax

Tags: registry, cmd, wsh

TO add this command using reg add

```
cscript %windir%\system32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-us\prnmngr.vbs -t -p "\\ipp://dc2.Mydomain.com\2F26P"
```

My Syntax is wrong, do you see my glaring failure?

```
REG ADD %KEY%\030 /V 1 /D "cscript %windir%\system32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-us\prnmngr.vbs -t -p "\\ipp://dc2.Mydomain.com\2F26P"" /f
```

Answer (score 0):

Believe there is a backslash missing on "\ipp